# animating a div with certain interval and place the element center of the page in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

here i am having a div which can be anywhere in a page and i want to move it from either right to left or left to right,and the movement will be like a animated motion of the div element....

Here the code what i tried...

**CSS**

```
.container{

width:300px;
height:400px;
margin-left:400px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
<div class="container"> </div>
</section>
```

**Script**

```
/* for mobile checking */
isMobile = {
    Android: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function () {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function () {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
function animatingDiv(refCls){
    if(isMobile.any()){
        $(refCls).attr('style','display:block !important;margin-left:auto !important;');
    }
    else{
        $(refCls).show();
        $(refCls).attr('style','display:block !important;');
        var centerWidth=$(document).outerWidth()/2 - ($(refCls).width() + ($(refCls).outerWidth() - $(refCls).width()))/2;
        $(refCls).animate({marginLeft:'='+centerWidth+'px'},2000, 'linear',function(){
            //$(this).attr('style','display:block !important;margin-left:auto !important;');
        });
    }   
}

$(function(){
    animatingDiv('section .container');
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    animatingDiv('section .container');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working pretty well, you have just to add `position: relative;` in the css side, and to remove the equal sign between the `marginLeft` and the `centerWidth` parameter.
See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3rwx8Ly/) link for a working example.
Hope it useful!!!